# How to add cover to opus audio file with ffmpeg or another command line tool

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, command-line-tool, opus

I searched nearly a whole day but found nothing to add a cover to an opus audio file.

I tried with kid3-cli and the following command.

```
kid3-cli -c 'set picture:"/home/pic.jpg" "desc"' "/path/to/*.opus"'
```

It just works when adding only a cover, if I add some other metatags like so

```
kid3-cli -c 'set album "ALBUM"'
```

then a random cover appears and I don't know where it come from. I can delete it but not add my own cover like in the above command. That random cover appears only in VLC latest version.

Somebody has a solution to add metatags and covers to opus, vorbis, aac, mp3, etc.

I installed foobar2000 and with the same command as above and vorbis audio data it's possible to attach a picture. In the GUI of foobar2000 under "Manage attached picture" I see the picture I attached.

But for opus still doesn't work.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: That cover is fetched from the internet based on the title and type of Music. Most of the times it is inaccurate. It didn't fetched the cover from the OPUS file.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this. I would recommend that you first try with the GUI version of Kid3 (use the latest version). If there are any erroneous existing tags, you can delete them with the "Remove" button, then save the file without tags, and then try to add new tags.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter. I used this command also to attach a picture to a vorbis audio file and there everything works. I use foobar2000 audio player to check. The same command don't work for opus there no picture is attached.